# How can I make a buffer with xxx meter by NetTopologySuite

Tags: c#, gis, jts

I am very new in NetTopologySuite, I work with the coordinatesystem in WGS84 by lon/lat, with the NetTopologySuite. I found the Buffer function to create a buffer with a distance, but how can I make a buffer with distance by the unit of meter? e.g make a 200 meter buffer of one point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetTopologySuite core library does not support WGS84 coordinates, or any other geodetic coordinate system.

To work around this limitation, you can convert your coordinates to a projected coordinate system (UTM for example, depending on your data), perform the buffer operation and than do the opposite conversion. [ProjNET](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI) supports such conversions.